# Calculation of Cyclomatic Complexity for Pseudocode

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

```
while(m<n)
  if(x>y) AND (a<b) then
    a=a+1
    y=y-1
  end if 
m=m+1
end while
```

i was calculating Cyclomatic Complexity of above pseudo code, and i came to conclusion with the short cut method that

M= (Decision Point) + 1

Where M is Cyclomatic Complexity

i Got answer 3

is it True?

Comment: Please Answer anyone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let identify every statement. Im using letters here, but it could be numbers instead.

```
A    while(m<n)              
B,C    if(x>y) AND (a<b) then
D        a=a+1
E        y=y-1
       end if 
F      m=m+1
G    end while
```

- Note that **the second statement have two conditions/predicates/decision points** (or whatever you call them), so i name them B and C.
- Im going to use `end while` (G) as the exit point.

Now we can draw the Control Flow Graph (CFG):

[image: CFG]

Finally, compute the Cyclomatic Complexity (M) in three different ways:

1. M = E-V+2*K = 9-7+2*1 = 4
2. M = C + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4
3. M = Regions(CFG) = 4

where:

- E=number of edges
- V=number of vertices
- K=number of graph components
- C=number of conditions/decision points

Answer (score 3):

As compare to above logic, @osEduSol mentioned is correct i.e.

M= (Decision Point) + 1

Where M is Cyclomatic Complexity

There are 3 decision point

i Got answer 4